# FocusChanged Event in Firebreath Framework

Tags: c++, firebreath

I am implementing the Firebreath Events like MouseDown,MouseUp,MouseMove in the JavaScript.
I want to implement Firebreath FocusChangedEvent also but i am confuse about the functionality of the FocusChanged event,I don't understand when the FocusChanged event fires.
To check the Functionality of the FocusChanged ,I have loaded two plugins but still not getting about same events.
I am referring this [Link](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/class%20FB%20FocusChangedEvent) .please anyone help for How that Event works and implementation of the Same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find what you want to know is to go look at where it is fired; events are not entirely consistently implemented on different platforms.  Depending on what you're using you'll want to look at one of the src/PluginAuto/[platform]/PluginWindow[something].[cpp|h|mm] files to see where it's coming from.